# Exchange Server Error ID 15021

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2013, ssl-certificate-errors

My Exchange Server 2013 writes "Error 15021" dozens of times in the Error log. It says, that there is an error using the SSL-Configuration. I googled the error but there seem to be a lot of hits concerning Port 443 but in my case it is Port 444.

```
netsh http show sslcert
```

shows some certs (more than needed as far I can tell).

My tries so far:

I checked the bindings and certs in IIS. On Port 444 there is no hostname entered and SNI is not activated as well in contrast to Port 443 (Hostname entered like hostname.domain.com)

The Certs selected are the same. Should I enter the hostname in the Binding on Port 444 as well?

In Windows Exchange Admin center there are multiple Certs but only one is associated with IIS. I am too afraid to delete the ones that seem not to be used.

Any hints?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have done some research and found a solution to resolve your issue:

*Deleted the certificate assigned to 0.0.0.0:444 by running netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:444 and assigned the same certificate as the one used on port 443 by running netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:444 certhash="certificate_hash" appid="application id", then restart the server and check if this issue continues.*

For more details: [An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:444](https://letsexchange.blogspot.com/2017/05/an-error-occurred-while-using-ssl.html?m=0)